# Does javac compile multiple files within the same directory when used to compile only main file?

Tags: java, file, class, compilation, program-entry-point

I'm using multiple java files in the same folder including one main file. Main file uses other files directly or indirectly.
Now I'm updating one file(not the main) but change is reflecting in main file when I compile and run main file only.

Comment: Yes, it recompiles all the .java files that depend on the one(s) you are compiling if they are out of date.

Answer (score 1):

[From the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#description) (emphasis mine):

> The order of source files specified on the command line or in an argument file is not important. javac will compile the files together, as a group, **and will automatically resolve any dependencies between the declarations in the various source files**.

You can demonstrate this by placing each of these files in a folder and running `javac Test.java`

---

Test.java

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.method();
    }

}
```

---

MyObject.java

```
class MyObject {

    void method() {
        System.out.println("method");
    }

}
```

---

Unused.java

```
class Unused {}
```

---

The files `Test.class` and `MyObject.class` will be created. `Unused.class` will not be created.